# Chrome extension code no longer running when tab inactive?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created a very simple Chrome extension for personal use that sent me a browser notification if a DOM element changed in a tab that had a specific site open and switch that tab to be the active one.

It would work if the tab was not active and open (intended/wanted behavior), but recently the notification no longer sends unless the tab is active. I haven't changed any of the code, so not sure if a recent Chrome update changed the behavior of the API.

Here's my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "New Element Notifier",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Creates notification if new element exists.",
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.website.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "website.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
 "web_accessible_resources": [
    "*.wav"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.type == "new-element") {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {active: true});

    var options = {
      type: "basic",
      title: "New Element",
      message: "A new element exists!",
      iconUrl: "icon.png"
    }

    chrome.notifications.create(options);

    sendResponse({confirm: "tab changed"});
  }
});
```

**website.js**

```
var elementContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".items-container")[0];

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'new-element'}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.confirm);
      });
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(elementContainer, {characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true});
```

Not sure what happened as it was working fine for a long time. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: The code seems fine. The site may have changed its scripts to pause when the page is not active, which is usually handled via Page Lifecycle API events. Try verifying the code in a much older portable Chrome - maybe it's a bug in new Chrome in which case you can [bisect](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) it.