# How to put selection text in chrome.contextMenus?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I add selection text in context.Menus?

I want to create a Chrome extension which will work similarly to the right-click search function in Google Chrome (i.e. right click on selected text ->  "Search 'selection text')

[I made a preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7vY5.png)

I assume this is something with [chrome.contextMenus.update](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus#method-update) but i don't know how to make it work

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  var context = "selection";
  var title = "Search";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": title,
    "contexts": [context],
    "id": "context" + context
  });
});

// add click event
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

// The onClicked callback function.
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  var sText = info.selectionText;
  var url = "https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=" + encodeURIComponent(sText);
  window.open(url, '_blank');
};
```

Comment: Add `%s` inside "Search", more info in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create). For an alternative/universal approach see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498281/chrome-extension-code-no-longer-running-when-tab-inactive).